# How can I "findstr" all links from a source-code of a webpage?

Tags: batch, script, grep, findstr

I want to have just the https-Link in a seperate file. How do to that without getting the complete line of the code, just the links?

[image]

Comment: That's not valid HTML (where is the `href="`?

Comment: already grepped it away and replaced it :-)

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a solution using `findstr` or `grep`?

Comment: findstr would be nice, grep is unix only right?

Comment: Generally, yes, but it has also been [compiled for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, [*do not try to parse HTML with regex...*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1347519)

---

[XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) can get you what you want - it was designed specifically for this:

```
//a/@href
```

Then to make use of the XPath with `xmllint` (other utilities will exist):

```
xmllint --shell --html file.html <<<'cat //a/@href'
```

That'll give you a bunch of stuff, including prompts (`/ >`), the attribute's name (`href="..."`) and separators (`-------`)... so filter them out, sort, and get a list of unique URLs:

```
xmllint --shell --html file.html <<<'cat //a/@href' \
    | sed '/^ href="/!d;s/^ href="//;s/"$//' \
    | sort \
    | uniq
```

All without `grep`.

Here, we use `sed` to:

1. `/^ href="/!d` - delete all lines that don't match the regex `^ href="`
2. `s/^ href="//` - snip off the prefix
3. `s/"$//` - snip off the suffix

---

Alternatively, you could use [CSS selectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Selector) instead of XPath, with [`tq`](https://github.com/plainas/tq) (a Python project):

```
tq 'a' -a href < file.html
```

---

Note: after the discussion around `grep`, I presumed Unix... If you have Cygwin or WSL, then this will probably work there too.

`xmllint` (a utility from [libxml2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libxml2)) has a Windows release.